# Powershell 4 - Setting processor affinity for runspaces and multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, powershell, affinity

I'd like to set the cpu-affinity of multiple particular threads.

All the references I've found so far deal with setting the cpu-affinity of a process(PID) but not a thread. Is there a way to accomplish this while using .Net Runspaces? Or am I trying to do something impossible?

The basic idea is: I have a 20 core box and would like to get the threads spread evenly between the cores. Otherwise they all wind up pounding on a single core.

Thanks!

Comment: 20 cores!  You suck!  ;-)  How are you causing the extra threads to be spun up?  Are you using the RunspacePool or something else?

Comment: Yep...its a big box :-)  Yes, I'm using runspace pools.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a .Net wrapper, but the Win32 api SetThreadAffinityMask does what you need - see documentation here:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure how that would tie into Runspaces. I don't suppose you have any examples?

Comment: An example: http://khason.net/blog/parallel-programming-well-it%E2%80%99s-all-about-cpu-affinity-or-how-to-set-processor-affinity-in-wpf/

Comment: Runspaces have a property ThreadOptions - if you use either ReuseThread (for runspace pools) or UseCurrentThread, you can be sure the runspace isn't creating new threads, so setting the thread affinity once per runspace should suffice.